# Hibernate UniqueResult Deprecated

Tags: hibernate

I've updated Hibernate to 5.2.2 version and the uniqueResult() method is deprecated. I'm reading de documentation but I can't find which method should I use to replace it? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I've been reading the documentation, instead of using the `uniqueResult()`, Hibernate propose the `getSingleResult()` method with a `try / catch` block. This is a better way of handling exceptions when the result is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Even I found the same problem. Apparently all types of queries using the **org.hibernate.query.Query class are deprecated.** Instead use **javax.persistence.TypedQuery** class, methods of this class are not deprecated.
But my knowledge of Hibernate is still limited.

Answer (score 0):

I used `getSingleResult()` with `try / catch` instead of `uniqueResult()` and worked. Be careful to catch `org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException` because I'm catching `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException` and don't work.