# How to return int from query?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hql

I have this method in my dao implementation, and im trying to return int from the query and put it in the roomNumber int variable, but im not sure if it`s the right syntax... and probably there are other errors. In debug mode i see that the int roomNumber field doesnt get any value, its value is 0 when i step over it.

```
@Override
    public int getRoomNumber(int bookingId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery("select room.roomId from Booking where bookingId=:bookingId");

        query.setParameter("bookingId", bookingId);

        int roomNumber = query.getFirstResult();

        return roomNumber;
    }
```

Booking table in db:

[image]

for the query i have tried also this:

```
select room_room_id from Booking where bookingId=:bookingId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these purposes there is method `uniqueResult()`:

```
int roomNumber = ((Number)query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

**EDIT**: if you use hibernate version > `5.2.2` you possibly will want change this to method `getSingleResult()`:

[Hibernate UniqueResult Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358422/hibernate-uniqueresult-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for your help... just a quick question, im getting a warning about uniqueResult():
"The method uniqueResult() from the type Query is deprecated" - this won't be a problem?

Comment: Oh, you are using Hibernate 5.x.x, right? I thought it is version < 5. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the follow up answer.